# Bootstrap slider: changing text with static background

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, text, background, slider

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I have a question about the slider: is it possible to keep the same background while only the text is changing/sliding? If yes, what is the correct code?

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 0):

Using the example from the bootstrap docs with a couple tweaks:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner"> /* set background on this element */
    <div class="item active">
     <div class="myplaceholder"></div> /* remove the <img> tags and replace with transparent div as a place holder */
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>This is the text that will scroll passed over a static background</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
```

One way of getting a static background would be to set the desired background on the `.carousel-inner`. Then replace the < img> elements with a div with no background color set.

```
.carousel-inner { background: red; }
.myplaceholder { height: 400px; width: 400px; }
```

This will allow the `.carousel-caption` element to be visible and appear to just scroll over the top of (in this case) a static red background. It's a bit of an ugly hack so you'd have to re think it if you wanted it to be responsive but hopefully this will set you on the right track.